# Should I adjust the value of a property when setting it or when getting it?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter, accessor, read-write

**Hello guys, please don't be too harsh. I am a beginner.**
What is the best practice for and what is the difference b/n the following:

**#1**

```
public SodaDateTime DteRegistered
{    
    get { return DateTimeUtil.NullDateForMaxOrMinDate(this._dteRegistered); }
    set
    {
        if (DateTimeUtil.IsNullDate(value))
        {
            this._dteRegistered = new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, DateTime.Today);
        }
        else
        {
            this._dteRegistered = new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**VS.** 
**#2**

```
public SodaDateTime DteRegistered
{
    get
    {
        if (DateTimeUtil.IsNullDate(this._dteRegistered))
        { 
            _dteRegistered = new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, DateTime.Today); 
        }
        return this._dteRegistered;
    }
    set { _dteRegistered = new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, value); }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that the first one calls `NullDateForMaxOrMinDate` and the second one doesn't, one does validation in the setter and the other in the getter. Which one you choose is a matter of opinion (which is why I voted to close), though I prefer doing validation in the setter. That is also where I would call `NullDateForMaxOrMinDate` (before setting the private backing field).

Comment: I concur on closing (Opinion request) and prefering validation in the setter. I would not use a silent override, but an exception as reactiong to a faulty SodaDateTIme. This is an issue "that should not be ignored" or silently fixed. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) I also wonder about this whole design: SodaDateTime seems to be derived of DateTime and adds 2 fields - 1 string and a reference to the class you assign it too? What is up with that?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft published a [Property Design Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) which provides the following guidance that I believe is applicable to your question:

**✓ DO** provide sensible default values for all properties, ensuring that the defaults do not result in a security hole or terribly inefficient code.

**✓ DO** preserve the previous value if a property setter throws an exception.

**X AVOID** throwing exceptions from property getters. Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method.

---

Based on the guidance that a property should have a valid default value and that getters should be simple operations, I would suggest that you do validation in the setter. It also might be reasonable to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the setter if the value passed is not valid, so that the client working with your class understands what's happening

```
// Provide reasonable default value
private SodaDateTime _dteRegistered = 
    new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, DateTime.Today);

// Getter is a simple operation without preconditions
public SodaDateTime DteRegistered
{    
    get { return _dteRegistered; }
    set
    {            
        if (value == null) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value cannot be null");
        }

        if (DateTimeUtil.IsNullDate(value)) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value cannot have a null date"); 
            // or: value = DateTime.Today;
        }

        this._dteRegistered = DateTimeUtil.NullDateForMaxOrMinDate(
            new SodaDateTime("DteRegistered", this, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ArgumentOutOfRangeException over ArgumentNullException?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad That's a great point. I'm not familiar with the `SodaDateTime` type, but if `value == null` then I'd definitely use `ArgumentNullException`. I updated my answer